# Cannot analyse project with sonar-maven-plugin after upgrade server from 4.0 to 4.5.1 (missing class org.sonar.plugins.java.api.JavaSettings)

Tags: java, maven, sonarqube, cobertura, sonarqube-4.5

I have upgraded SonarQube from 4.0 to 4.5.1 , and also the java plugin from 1.4 to 2.9.1, but after triggering the job I got the below error. I would like to know if this is because of the Cobertura plugin(1.4) which I am using at present. should i upgrade cobertura plugin to 1.6.3?

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.codehaus.mojo:sonar-maven-plugin:2.7.1:sonar
  (default-cli) on project mmsc: Execution default-cli of goal
  org.codehaus.mojo:sonar-maven-plugin:2.7.1:sonar failed: A required class
   was missing while executing org.codehaus.mojo:sonar-maven-plugin:2.7.1:sonar:
    Lorg/sonar/plugins/java/api/JavaSettings;
    [ERROR] -----------------------------------------------------
    [ERROR] realm =    plugin>org.codehaus.mojo:sonar-maven-plugin:2.7.1
    [ERROR] strategy = org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.strategy.SelfFirstStrategy
    [ERROR] urls[0] = file:/cip/home/jenkins/.m2/repository/org/codehaus/mojo/sonar-maven-plugin/2.7.1/sonar-maven-plugin-2.7.1.jar
    [ERROR] urls[1] = file:/cip/home/jenkins/.m2/repository/org/apache/maven/shared/maven-dependency-tree/2.1/maven-dependency-tree-2.1.jar
    [ERROR] urls[2] = file:/cip/home/jenkins/.m2/repository/backport-util-concurrent/backport-util-concurrent/3.1/backport-util-concurrent-3.1.jar
    [ERROR] urls[3] = file:/cip/home/jenkins/.m2/repository/org/codehaus/plexus/plexus-interpolation/1.11/plexus-interpolation-1.11.jar
    [ERROR] urls[4] = file:/cip/home/jenkins/.m2/repository/org/codehaus/plexus/plexus-component-annotations/1.5.5/plexus-component-annotations-1.5.5.jar
    [ERROR] urls[5] = file:/cip/home/jenkins/.m2/repository/org/eclipse/aether/aether-util/0.9.0.M2/aether-util-0.9.0.M2.jar
    [ERROR] urls[6] = file:/cip/home/jenkins/.m2/repository/org/sonatype/plexus/plexus-sec-dispatcher/1.4/plexus-sec-dispatcher-1.4.jar
    [ERROR] urls[7] = file:/cip/home/jenkins/.m2/repository/org/codehaus/plexus/plexus-utils/1.5.5/plexus-utils-1.5.5.jar
    [ERROR] urls[8] = file:/cip/home/jenkins/.m2/repository/org/sonatype/plexus/plexus-cipher/1.4/plexus-cipher-1.4.jar
    [ERROR] urls[9] = file:/cip/home/jenkins/.m2/repository/org/sonarsource/sonar-runner/sonar-runner-api/2.5-RC1/sonar-runner-api-2.5-RC1.jar
    [ERROR] urls[10] = file:/cip/home/jenkins/.m2/repository/commons-lang/commons-lang/2.6/commons-lang-2.6.jar
    [ERROR] urls[11] = file:/cip/home/jenkins/.m2/repository/com/google/guava/guava/10.0.1/guava-10.0.1.jar
    [ERROR] urls[12] = file:/cip/home/jenkins/.m2/repository/com/google/code/findbugs/jsr305/2.0.3/jsr305-2.0.3.jar
    [ERROR] Number of foreign imports: 1
    [ERROR] import: Entry[import  from realm ClassRealm[maven.api, parent: null]]
    [ERROR] 
    [ERROR] -----------------------------------------------------:
```

Missing class: `org.sonar.plugins.java.api.JavaSettings`

Comment: can you precise which version of maven you are using ?

Comment: we are using maven-3.0.4 version.

Comment: can you try with a more recent version of maven ?

Answer (score 1):

You should upgrade all Java plugins.

---

From mailing list ([Error during analysis Sonar 4.3](http://sonarqube-archive.15.x6.nabble.com/Error-during-analysis-Sonar-4-3-td5025528.html)):

> [Julien Henry](https://stackexchange.com/users/255011): You should have a plugin that rely on JavaSettings that was removed. Can you list all your installed plugins/versions.

---

Class has been deleted in version 2.2 ([see GrepCode](http://grepcode.com/search?query=org.sonar.plugins.java.api.JavaSettings&start=0&entity=type&n=)).